# InDesign CC: Text not filling all of text boxes

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am using Indesign CC to make a newsletter from a template/grandfathered document. It has a 2 column design with images and captions etc. to go with the main text which has headings within it.

For some reason at the bottom of the text boxes it flows over to the next column/page but leaves a gap big enough for 3 or 4 sentences. The text box won't fill unless I make it bigger than the page, and then text flows all the way down. If I move it back it goes back to the white space. Any ideas about what's happening and how to fix it?

Comment: This is impossible for anyone to answer without seeing the actual file. Could be a text wrap, space before/space after... many, many things.

Comment: One of the possibilities is that there's an element with a text wrap in the way. But that's only one of many possible causes.

Comment: My bet is on Keep Together settings. But let's see a screen shot.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Ctrl+B or right click on the box for Text Frame Options - it's likely you have 'Balance Columns' checked - which may be causing your issue.

1) Select the content box and right click for 'Text Frame Options' or hit Ctrl+B
2) In Text Frame Options, check or uncheck 'Balance Columns' as required

Screen shots show columns both unbalanced and balanced. 
Hope this helps *._.*

[image: Select content box and right click for Text Frame options or hit Ctrl+B]

[image: In Text Frame Options, check or uncheck 'Balance Columns' as required]